# MySQL can't create pid file: Permission Denied

Tags: mysql, root, osx-mavericks

I'm using MySQL on my macbook pro, which worked fine for the last 2 years.
A week ago it suddenly stopped and I'm not able to restart it again.

I've changed the permission on `/usr/local/mysql` to 0777 and also changed the owner to mysql.

When I try to start mysql (`sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe` or `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start`),
I get onf of the following errors:

```
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/[COMPUTERNAME].pid)
```

or

```
mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/[COMPUTERNAME].pid ended.
```

When I open the .err file, I see this errors:

```
140222  8:10:30 [ERROR] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/usr/local/mysql/data/[COMPUTERNAME].pid' (Errcode: 13)

140222  8:10:30 [ERROR] Can't start server: can't create PID file: Permission denied
```

**Edit:**

Here is the ouput of `sudo ls -ld / /usr /usr/local /usr/local/mysql /usr/local/mysql/data /usr/local/mysql-5.6.16-osx10.7-x86_64`

```
drwxr-xr-x  36 root    wheel  1292 Feb 20 21:16 /
drwxr-xr-x@ 12 root    wheel   408 Oct 26 10:12 /usr
drw-r--r--  49 root    wheel  1666 Feb 22 09:06 /usr/local
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root    wheel    27 Feb 22 09:06 /usr/local/mysql -> mysql-5.6.16-osx10.7-x86_64
drwxr-xr-x  17 _mysql  wheel   578 Feb 22 09:06 /usr/local/mysql-5.6.16-osx10.7-x86_64
drwxr-xr-x  10 _mysql  wheel   340 Feb 22 09:07 /usr/local/mysql/data
```

Running `ls -ld /usr/local/mysql/data/*.pid` gives `ls: /usr/local/mysql/data/*.pid: No such file or directory`

Comment: Put the output of `ls -ld / /usr /usr/local /usr/local/mysql /usr/local/mysql/data ; ls -ld /usr/local/mysql/data/*.pid` into your question.

Comment: @JdeBP I have updated the question with the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> drw-r--r--  49 root    wheel  1666 Feb 22 09:06 /usr/local

There you have it, right in front of you.  Execute (directory traversal) permission denied.  To the mysql user and indeed to everyone else.

The permissions and ownership of `/usr/local` are a widely-hit problem in Mac OS 10, for many reasons that I'm not going to elaborate here.

```
chmod a+x /usr/local
```

(run as the superuser of course) is your friend.

Avoid suggestions to change the ownership or group of the directory.  They are a security disaster waiting to happen, [as several people have noted](http://howtonode.org/introduction-to-npm#disqus_thread) in [places where this has come up before](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69549/).

Comment: I had to add write perms to wheel group and it worked
`sudo chmod -R g+w /usr/local/mysql`